# C#: Hyperlink in the first gridview stops working when the 2nd gridview in the same page gets populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have 2 gridviews in a page. The first one gets data when the page loads and the 2nd gridview gets the data when a button is clicked. Before the 2nd gridview is populated with data, the hyperlink in the first gridview works just fine. But as soon as the button is clicked and the 2nd gridview is populated, the hyperlink in the first gridview doesn't work. Its appearance resembles a hyperlink but when I point cursor on it, it doesn't display the link nor it opens up the url. However, the hyperlinks in the 2nd gridview work fine.

**Gridview whose hyperlink doesn't work after the button is clicked:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataSourceID="Saved_Work" Style="float: left; font-size: small; position: relative;
                width: 82%; position: relative; top: 0px; height: 55px; font-size: small; text-align: left;
                left: 30px;" align="left">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="Continue_SavedWork"  runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/EditSavedJob.aspx?ID={0}") %>'
                                Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="UserID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Created" HeaderText="Date_Created" SortExpression="Date_Created" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

**Button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="FillGridView" Text="Search" Style="font-size: small;
                position: relative; text-align: left; top: 0px; left: 280px; border: 1px ridge #2F10AB" />
```

**Gridview which gets bind on a button click:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="27px" OnRowUpdating="EditStatus_Click"
                Style="left: 120px; position: relative; width: 82%; top: 0px; text-align: center;
                font-size: small;" Width="361px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobNumber" HeaderText="JobNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobLocation" HeaderText="JobLocation" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("JobID", "~/JobDetails.aspx?JobID={0}") %>'
                                Text='Edit Job' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="Tickets" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Tickets.aspx?JobId={0}&JobNumber={1}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("JobId").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("JobNumber").ToString())) %>'
                                Text='Tickets' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDD" runat="server" Style="position: relative; font-size: small;
                                left: 5%; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; border: 1px ridge #2F10AB; background-color: #F7F7F7"
                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Submitted</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Closed</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Void</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download PDF">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("JobID", "~/GeneratePDF.aspx?JobID={0}") %>' Text='View' />--%>
                            <asp:Button ID="View" runat="server" OnClick="View_Click" Text="PDF" Style="text-align: right" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

**Server side code for the button:**

```
protected void FillGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridLabel.Enabled = true;
        GridLabel.Text = "Search Results";
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["test_rashmiConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            StringBuilder sbCommand = new
                StringBuilder("select J.JobNumber,J.Status,J.JobID,C.Name as CustomerName, C.StartDate,C.JobLocation from JobDetails J inner join CustomerDetails C on J.CustomerID=C.ID where 1=1 ");

            if (CustomerName.Text != "")
            {
                sbCommand.Append(" AND C.Name=@CustomerName");
                SqlParameter param = new
                    SqlParameter("@CustomerName", CustomerName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            if (JobNumber.Text != "")
            {
                sbCommand.Append(" AND J.JobNumber=@JobNumber");
                SqlParameter param = new
                    SqlParameter("@JobNumber", JobNumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            if (FromDate.Text != "" && ToDate.Text != "")
            {
                sbCommand.Append(" AND C.StartDate between @FromDate and @ToDate");
                SqlParameter param1 = new
                    SqlParameter("@FromDate", FromDate.Text);
                SqlParameter param2 = new
                    SqlParameter("@ToDate", ToDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
            }
            if (JobLocation.Text != "")
            {
                sbCommand.Append(" AND C.JobLocation= @JobLocation ");
                SqlParameter param = new
                    SqlParameter("@JobLocation", JobLocation.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            sbCommand.Append(" Order by C.StartDate desc");

            if (CustomerName.Text == "" && JobNumber.Text == "" && FromDate.Text == "" && ToDate.Text == "" && JobLocation.Text == "")
            {
                sbCommand = new StringBuilder("select top 10 J.JobNumber,J.Status,J.JobID,C.Name as CustomerName, C.StartDate,C.JobLocation from JobDetails J inner join CustomerDetails C on J.CustomerID=C.ID where 1=1 Order by C.StartDate desc");
            }

            cmd.CommandText = sbCommand.ToString();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = rdr;          
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView2.DataSource = Saved_Work;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls post both the aspx code as well as the server side code

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah, I have edited my post with the code included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that other controls were also disabled after the 2nd gridview was getting populated. Then I noticed that the div which was holding the button and 1st gridview whose hyperlink wasn't working had height less than the 1st gridview. So whatever controls were outside the main div's height were getting disabled after the 2nd gridview was getting populated. I increased the height of the main div and it fixed the issue.